# Real-time progress bar updates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When updating a progress bar or other progress indicator in real-time to reflect activity going on in an app's processing, I see no way to do this without using this clever code snippet:

`[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantPast]];`

Otherwise, the progress bar waits until the run loop finishes, in which case it then jumps to the progress bar's conclusion.

If you want to update progress during a single run loop (or what I perceive to be a single run loop), is this the only way to do so?

How are progress bars *typically* coded to update in real-time?

Is the above code *dangerous*? I really don't know much about direct manipulation of the run loop, and it makes me nervous to do something in an app that I don't understand. This code works, but is it a good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your lengthy operation on a background thread/NSOperationQueue/GCD and update the UI periodically. The UI always runs on the main thread so the update will to effect quickly. Try something like this:

```
for (...) {
  // some process
  // ...

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
    [self.progressIndicator setProgress:x animated:YES];
  });
}
```

In general you don't want to run long or complex operations on the main thread as it will block the whole UI.

Comment: in my case, it is running on a background thread but I'm trying to figure out how to send progress information.

Answer (score 1):

i am using `NSTimer` for this kind of need. let's say you are going to play/stream an audio file and you need to show duration with the progress bar's position so this is my way.

hope this helps..

Comment: can you show a little more about how you do this? what is in the method that your timer calls repeatedly? how is it getting the information it needs?

Comment: this is the timer i create :
'myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkSearchResult:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[myTimer fire];'
and then

'- (void) checkSearchResult:(NSTimer*)theTimer' is called so that the place you are going to play with you progressbar , and also if you are playing audio without streaming you can get its duration from the avplayeritem/avplayer , by this you can set or if you are streaming then you will increase a variable of your own to know which second you are in..
hope this helps..